# Plot a map in VEGA-LITE with selection feature for year where selected year used to fill map

Tags: maps, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I have csv file in format

```
pop2010, pop2022, pop2023
2193, 2183, 3021
```

Now i added a selection param which will be used to directly change the map rendering column however it doesnt have any output on the map, i dont know whats wrong as there are no errors. Below is my code

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "title": "World Population in 2023",
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 450,
    "data": {
        "url": "data/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.topojson",
        "format": { "type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"}
    },
    "projection": { "type": "equalEarth"},
        "params": [
            {
                "name": "Pop_Filter",
                "value": 0,
                "bind": {
                    "input": "range",
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 130000000,
                    "step": 10000000,
                    "name": "Population > "
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "SelectedYear",
                "value": "datum.pop2023",
                "bind": {
                    "input": "select",
                    "options": ["datum.pop2010", "datum.pop2022", "datum.pop2023"],
                    "labels": ["2010 Population", "2022 Population", "2023 Population"],
                    "name": "Select Year"
                }
            }
        ],
    
    "layer": [
        {
            "data": {
              "url": "data/oceans.topojson",
              "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "oceans"}
            },
            "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": "#97dbee"} 
        },

        {
            "data": {
              "url": "data/WorldMapWithGraticules.topojson",
              "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_graticules_30"}
            },
            "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "fill": null, "stroke": "white"} 
        },

        {
            "transform": [
                {
                    "lookup": "properties.NAME",
                    "from": {
                        "data": {
                            "url": "data/countries-table.csv"
                        },
                        "key": "country",
                        "fields": ["pop2010", "pop2022", "pop2023"]
                    }
                },
                {"calculate": "SelectedYear", "as": "Population 2023"},
                {"filter": "SelectedYear > Pop_Filter"}
            ],
            "mark": {"type": "geoshape", "stroke": "white"},
            "encoding": {
                "color": {
                    "field": "Population 2023",
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "scale": {"type": "log"}
                },
                "tooltip": [
                    { "field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "Country" },
                    { "field": "SelectedYear", "title":"Population in 2023", "type": "quantitative", "format": "-s"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Trying to Render dynamic map in vegalite where user chooses year however its not showing up